# Conditions when $||x||_2 < ||y||_2 \rightarrow ||x||_1 < ||y||_1 $ holds?

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

Given that $x$ and $y$ are vectors in an n-dimensional vector space. Then when does the following identity hold ? i.e can we identify conditions in which the following identity holds ?
$$||x||_2 < ||y||_2 \rightarrow ||x||_1 < ||y||_1  $$

I am specially interested in the case when $x,y \in [0,1]^{n}$

Answer (score 0):

This is not true in general. Take $n=2$ and the points $ x=(1,0) $, $y=(3/5,3/5)$. We have $\|x\|_2 = 1$, $\|y\|_2 = \sqrt{18}/5 \approx 0.8485$ and $ \|x\|_1 = 1$, $\|y\|_1 = 6/5$.

Comment: I am interested in " when does the following identity hold ? i.e can we identify conditions in which the following identity holds ?
"